# Выгрузить графики из grafana

Tags: график, grafana

Стоит задача в получении графиков из графаны. Использую следующий запрос:
http://mygrafana:3000/render/dashboard-solo/db/board?&orgId=1&panelId=13&from=1505750400000&to=1505894400000&width=1000&height=500&theme=light , я получаю график следующего вида:

[image: График]

Если указывать меньший интервал времени (например 8 часов), то график выгружается корректно (Обычно графики должны браться за интервал > 14 часов).
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с данной проблемой и знает как ее можно решить?

Comment: А Zabbix тут при чём? И Java?

Comment: А, понял, вы не нашли соответствующую метку и поставили "хоть что-нибудь", т. к. репутации для создания меток у вас пока нет. Сделал вам метку.